FFmpeg macos binary not supporting RTMPS, How can build my custom macos binary with statically linked to openssl for RTMPS
I go to https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-118163-g954d55c2a4.7z and download latest ffmpeg macos binary, But I am not able to use RTMPS protocol.
